# If the redshift of CMBR is 1100 is then possible find an object as a protogalaxy at e.g. redshift 100?

Tags: astrophysics, astronomy, redshift

If the redshift of CMBR is 1100 is then possible find an object as a protogalaxy at e.g. redshift 100? If the telescope 'James Webb' can 'look' very far should it detect some very distant objects which light is elongated at wavelength of 50 micrometers(redshift=100)? ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends a bit on what exactly you mean by "protogalaxy":

If you mean a cloud of gas which has just collapsed and started forming its first generation of stars, then the answer is "**No**".

If you mean an overdensity in the field of gas and dark matter which has resisted expansion and will eventually collapse to form a galaxy… well, then the answer is also "**No**".

##### Galaxies formed later

Regarding the first interpretation of the word "protogalaxy", a redshift of $z\simeq100$ corresponds to an age of the Universe of only ~16 million years, at which time we're pretty sure no stars or galaxies had yet formed. The overdensities that would eventually turn into galaxies were there, but theoretical calculations (e.g. [Barkana & Loeb 2001](https://ui.adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/2001PhR...349..125B)), numerical simulations (e.g. [Abel et al. 2002](https://ui.adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/2002Sci...295...93A)), and indirect observations ([Bowman et al. 2018](https://ui.adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/2018Natur.555...67B)) strongly indicate that the first luminous sources did not form until at least after 100 million years. This corresponds to redshifts $z\sim20\text{–}30$.

##### The Dark Ages

Regarding the second interpretation, the seeds for the structure were there from the beginning (i.e. since the Big Bang), so if that's what you mean by "protogalaxy", they were present at $z=100$. In this case, however, there is virtually no light emitted — we're in the [Dark Ages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chronology_of_the_universe#Dark_Ages) where the Universe still consists of its primordial hydrogen and helium. The temperature of the gas at this time is 275 K, around the freezing point of water, and the density is too low for frequent collisions of atoms. The only light emitted is the occasional [hydrogen spin flip transition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydrogen_line), but the wavelength of this light is 21 cm, i.e. in the radio regime which James Webb cannot detect. In fact, with current technology not even a radio telescope would be able to detect such faint light.